# Javafx tableview show overall downloadspeed in a Label

Tags: javafx, tableview, download

I have an TableView which shows the progress, speed, and so on, for any download. Now i want to show the overall downloadspeed in a Label or so, but i have currently no idea how to solve this problem. Each download is independent.

For the table is use the setCellValueFactory

```
@FXML
private TableView<Download> downloadTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Download, String> filenameColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Download, Double> progressColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Download, String> downloadSpeedColumn;

@FXML
private void initialize(){
    filenameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().filenameProperty());

    progressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().progressProperty().asObject());
    progressColumn.setCellFactory(ProgressBarTableCell.<DownloadContainer>forTableColumn());

    downloadSpeedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().transferSpeedProperty());
}

public void setMain(Main main){
    downloadTable.setItems(main.getDownloads());
}
```

For starting Downloadthreads i use an Executorservice with fixedThreadPool.

I thought to iterate over the downloadList and add each speed, but i don't know who to trigger that update?!?

I'm open for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the observable list of Download with an [extractor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-) that returns an array including the `transferSpeedProperty`, it will fire update notifications whenever any of the transfer speed properties of any elements change.

So create your list using something like

```
ObservableList<Download> downloads 
    = FXCollections.observableArrayList(download -> new Observable[] {download.transferSpeedProperty()});
```

Then you can do

```
DoubleBinding overallProgress = Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> 
    downloads.stream().collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Download::getTransferSpeed)),
    downloads);
```

and

```
Label overallTransferSpeedLabel = new Label();
overallTransferSpeedLabel.textProperty().bind(overallProgress.asString());
```

Comment: I have done it like you suggest, but I get "Exception in thread "Thread-x" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-x"

Comment: That means you are updating the transfer speed from a background thread: you can't do that if you want it to result in a change to the UI. It's really a different question, but [it's been asked many many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+not+on+fx+application+thread) on this forum.

Comment: I read many of them, but i think I'm to dumb to fix it. I'm going to us a timer and platform.runlater which updates every few seconds.
Thanks anyway!